# How to execute Automation script of web application to mobile browser platforms

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

i have E commerce application for both mobile and website, we have to do automation for both the platforms  and have to share the reports with clients.

How to create the two instances in single script, ie web and mobile browser together?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tests are written using Selenium, you can use [Appium](http://appium.io/) for launching the mobile browser.

You need to create object of AndroidDriver (or IOSDriver as applicable) to launch the browser on the target Mobile Device. These drivers work pretty much like remotewebdriver.

Now you can pass the target device from the config file (or properties) and select the driver you want to launch (AnroidDriver or IOSDriver or IEDriver). you will get a lot of example **[Here](https://github.com/appium/sample-code/tree/master/sample-code/examples/java)**. I am providing you a small code snippet to launch AndroidDriver

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus 6P");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0.2");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.chrome");

    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.google.android.apps.chrome.ChromeTabbedActivity");
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);}
```

Here http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub is the location of appium server.

Comment: i know how to write script with the help of appium ,my concern is this if i have written webdriver script for web application ,in the same script how can i add appium code ,so that same code can run for both wen and mobile,or else i can use Testng

Comment: @snig Theoritically your webdriver scripts should work as is depending on the app framework you are using. If your application is responsive then you might have to implement keywords so that in case of mobile you use a different flow than as in web browser.

For example: Facebook gives you option of creating account on landing page in desktop browser but on mobile browser you have an extra step to click on 'Create New Account' button. After that all the create account page object are same.

Comment: u are not getting my point ,if u have any sample code even on GIT ,do let me know

Comment: give me a sample app and I will see if I can write a quick test.